# Windows Alternative to Thunar/Nautilus Custom Actions?

Tags: file-management, shell-scripting, bash

In the Linux file managers Thunar and Nautilus you can create custom actions. When right-clicking on a file bash scripts tailored for particular files can be run. Is there a file manager or program in Windows that has this feature?

Comment: Raw guess: AFAIK *Total Commander* can do that. Not being a Windows user, I'm not sure about the details, hence only a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MultiCommander](http://multicommander.com/) offers custom actions.

- Free, Gratis
- Customizable keyboard shortcuts
- Customizable mouse actions
- Plug In extensions
- Much more

One of the options for custom commands is to run a batch file.